# High speed rotary encoder with Arduino MEGA

Tags: arduino-mega, interrupt, rotary-encoder

I'm trying to develop length measuring system and I'm using a industrial rotary encoder as the sensor.

A have decided to use an Arduino external interrupt for connect the encoder. But, Encoder will rotate very fast. I need to calculate PPR(Pulse per revolution) of the encoder according to maximum interrupt frequency of Arduino MEGA.

So, What is the maximum interrupt frequency of Arduino MEGA?

Comment: it depends on the program that you are running

Comment: Using the atmega's counter module might be the way to go